# How to add permissions for user for only one directory inside another directory on Samba?

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, samba, share

I'm newbie in Windows. I have a Windows domain controller on samba. On this controller there are some shares. Each of this share has configured security group with full access. Group G1 has full access to share S1. Ofcourse each user in group G1 can modify files/folders in this share S1. In S1 i have 3 folders - F1, F2, F3. Is there a way to create user U1 which will have access to e.g. F2?

I would like to mount in U1's laptop S1 as network drive. After entering this drive he should se F1, F2 and F3 but should be able only to get into F2.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are on a Windows server having NTFS permissions on your drive, you have very versatile control over user/group rights over any folder and file (*Samba* being re-implementation of SMB/CIFS). While on Unix you are limited on to user/group/all permissions and need to design your file hierarchy accordingly, on Windows you can set up permissions to several groups on the same share, folder and file. I prefer using group permissions rather than direct user permissions.

In your situation user U1 must have permissions (directly or through a group):

- Read and write permissions on the SMB share `\\SERVER\share`. (Users can't use their folder and file permissions if there's no corresponding permission on the share, too.)
- Read permissons on folder `share\S1\` in order to see the `F2`.
- Read and write permissions on `share\S1\F2`.
- No permissions (or deny) on `share\S1\F1` and `share\S1\F3` etc.